# Nuget Package Installs Via Console But No Reference Added For C++ Project

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-studio-2015, nuget, nuget-package

I am trying to install the NuGet package detailed on this webpage: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/storage-c-plus-plus-how-to-use-blobs

For reference, the instructions are:

> Windows: In Visual Studio, click Tools > NuGet Package Manager > Package Manager Console. Type the following command into the NuGet Package Manager console and press ENTER.

This works... kind of.  The package is downloaded locally, but the reference isn't being added to my project.  When I install the package manually or from the PM Console, no reference is added.

Instructions I've been able to find (such as [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/tools/package-manager-console)) just insist that the references will be automagically added.  Which is great when it works, but it provides no debug reference point or how to add them manually.

Are there other options I'm missing?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For those that stumble onto the question, there is no working solution.  The issue arose because I was creating a UAP app, and the given Nuget package does not have UAP support.  At that point, in order to continue I must download the source code for the Nuget package and recompile it with the -ZW flag.

See here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt186162.aspx

> If you have source code for the DLL or static library, you can recompile with /ZW as a UWP project.

Comment: Glad to know that you have resolved this issue. Please mark your answer which is benefit to other communities who has the same problem.

Comment: Fixed, my bad! Better late than never.

Answer (score 1):

> the reference isn't being added to my project. When I install the package manually or from the PM Console, no reference is added

That is because **NuGet cannot directly add references to native projects, the ‘native’ target framework is not recognized within the \lib folder**.
For the detail information, you can refer to the [Support for Native Projects](http://blog.nuget.org/20130426/native-support.html).

Besides, after installed the wastorage package, you will notice that the **blob.h** and **storage_account.h** were added to External Dependencies:

[image]

Then you can add the following include statements to the top of the C++ file successfully where you want to use the Azure storage APIs to access blobs:

```
#include <was/storage_account.h>
#include <was/blob.h>
```

Update:
According to the JuniorIncanter comment, add the .targets, and .props file in the .vcxproj:

```
  <ImportGroup Label="ExtensionTargets">
<Import Project="..\packages\cpprestsdk.v120.windesktop.msvcstl.dyn.rt-dyn.2.9.1\build\native\cpprestsdk.v120.windesktop.msvcstl.dyn.rt-dyn.targets" Condition="Exists('..\packages\cpprestsdk.v120.windesktop.msvcstl.dyn.rt-dyn.2.9.1\build\native\cpprestsdk.v120.windesktop.msvcstl.dyn.rt-dyn.targets')" />
<Import Project="..\packages\cpprestsdk.v140.windesktop.msvcstl.dyn.rt-dyn.2.9.1\build\native\cpprestsdk.v140.windesktop.msvcstl.dyn.rt-dyn.targets" Condition="Exists('..\packages\cpprestsdk.v140.windesktop.msvcstl.dyn.rt-dyn.2.9.1\build\native\cpprestsdk.v140.windesktop.msvcstl.dyn.rt-dyn.targets')" />
<Import Project="..\packages\wastorage.v120.3.0.0\build\native\wastorage.v120.targets" Condition="Exists('..\packages\wastorage.v120.3.0.0\build\native\wastorage.v120.targets')" />
<Import Project="..\packages\wastorage.v140.3.0.0\build\native\wastorage.v140.targets" Condition="Exists('..\packages\wastorage.v140.3.0.0\build\native\wastorage.v140.targets')" />
```

Comment: "blob.h and storage_account.h were added to External Dependencies" They were not.  

Do I need to manually add a “.props” file and/or a “.targets” file?  If so, are there instructions somewhere I can follow for what these files should contain?

Comment: I just followed the following steps and was unable to repro the situation in your screenshot:

1)Launch VS2015
2)File->New->Project
3)Select Win32 Project -> OK
4)Finish
5)Right-click References -> Manage Nuget Packages
6)Browse -> type 'wastorage' in search
7)Select 'wastorage' (top link) -> Install
8)Check PM log, says successful install

No reference added, no header files added.  What step/setting am I missing?

Comment: If you could include your .vcxproj, .targets, and .props file for this dummy project that would be much appreciated.  At least having a reference would be helpful.

Comment: @JuniorIncanter , No need to add  a “.props” file and/or a “.targets” file manually, nuget will add them. I followed your steps in Visual Studio 2015 update3, the header files were added, so please double check the header files and have try to update your Visual Studio 2015 to update 3. Whether it works fine after you add #include <was/storage_account.h>
#include <was/blob.h> statements to the top of the C++ file ? Besides, I have updated my answer with .targets files.